# Is iAds not available for iPad apps?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, iad

I have an iPad app, which has a requirement for iAds. But in Library I could not find Ad Banner View.

Is iAds not available for iPad? I am using iOS SDK 4.1.

What are the other alternatives for implementing in an iPad app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using iOS SDK 4.2, because iPad only supports iAd banners in iOS 4.2 and later.

From your comment:

> no I am on iOS SDK 4.1

Since you are using an older version of iOS SDK, Ad BannerView will not appear in your Interface Builder Library. You'll have to upgrade by downloading the new SDK from developer.apple.com. Remember to upgrade your Xcode project to build against the new SDK.