# ADBanner is not appearing on the iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, adbannerview

I am trying to add a ADBanner view on my app (iPhone version, not universal) using [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app).

It's all working fine on the iPhone simulator but that ADBanner is not at all appearing on the iPad simulator as well as iPad (device). What might be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BasicBanner and ContainerBanner are configured to support both iPhone and iPad idioms, the TabbedBanner and NavigationBanner to support only the iPhone idiom, and the SplitViewBanner to support only the iPad idiom.

Refer [iad-not-working-on-ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243188/iad-not-working-on-ipad) link.

if using older version refer [s-iads-not-available-for-ipad-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468069/is-iads-not-available-for-ipad-apps)link. Hope helpful.